# searching <li> content based on after hyphen words using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one search text box for search li content.Searching results only based on li content after hyphen words.

This is li content:
Director-**MacLeod Conner**

i want to display li searching words based on **MacLeod Conner**. not Director.
how do it?help anyone.

HTML:

```
     <li><input type='checkbox'  name='' class='' value="1"><div>Director-MacLeod Conner</div></li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'  name='' class='' value="2"><div>Director-Dolores Arnold</div></li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'  name='' class='' value="3"><div>Music Directer-Blake Francis</div></li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'  name='' class='' value="4"><div>Autitor-Chavarin Deanna</div></li>
      <li><input type='checkbox'  name='' class='' value="5"><div>Director-Robert</div></li>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
$('ul#toList > li').hide();
$(document).on('click', '#btn1', function(e) {        
                 var Textnew=$("#textNew").val();   
                 if(Textnew.length>=3){         
                   var matches = $('ul#toList').find( 'li:contains('+ $( "#textNew" ).val() +')');
                   $( 'li', 'ul#toList' ).not( matches ).slideUp();
                   matches.slideDown();  
                 }
                 else{
                 $('ul#toList > li').hide();     
                 }

          });
```

});

Fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/6QDJM/17/

Comment: What is problem of your jsfiddle?

Comment: searching result only match with after hyphen words in li content

Answer (score 0):

There's no selector available to accomplish this.  So instead of `find` you can use `filter` with a function and hide the elements directly:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on('click', '#btn1', function(e) {
    var Textnew=$("#textNew").val();   
    if(Textnew.length>=3){      
      $('ul#toList li')
        .show()
        .filter(function(index){
          var parts = $(this).find('div').text().split('-');
          return (parts[1].indexOf(Textnew) == -1);
        })
        .slideUp();
    } else{
       $('ul#toList > li').show();   
    }
  });
});
```

This goes through each `li` and splits the text by hyphen.  Then it compares just the part of the string after the hyphen with your search text.

Comment: @poomanir I changed a few things to make it all simpler.  Check it out now.

Comment: @poomanir: 'not working' is not a problem description anyone can be reliably expected to work with, or understand. If something is 'not working' state exactly how it is not working, what it does that is wrong, and what it does not do that it *should* do.

Comment: Working super..Thank you so much

Comment: @poomanir Great! Since you're new to SO I'll mention it's standard to accept an answer so others can see it's solved.